# When using Rest Assured, if I send a post request to summit data to server, how can I write "ABC":["XYZ"] this value in LinkedHashmap

Tags: java, rest-assured, linkedhashmap

Request body is:-

```
{
"request":
{
  "body": 
{
    "ABC":["XYZ"],
    "PASSWORD": "password"
  }
}
```

MY CODE:-

I am getting error in response because the ABC value is going in string format

```
    Map body = new LinkedHashMap(6);
    body.put("ABC","XYZ");
    body.put("PASSWORD","password");
```

what is the correct way to write this request body using LinkedHashMap in restAssured

"ABC":["XYZ"],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need change it to `List<String>`

```java
body.put("ABC", Arrays.asList("XYZ"));
```